# Can't set value of structure variable

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure defined in quaternions.c

```
typedef struct quaternion{
        double arr[4];
} quaternion;
```

with header file

```
#ifndef QUATERNIONS_H
#define QUATERNIONS_H

typedef struct quaternion{
        double arr[4];
} quaternion;

#endif
```

Since this is my first time using C structures, I tried testing it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "quaternions.h"
        
int main(){
        quaternion a;
        a.arr[1]=2.5;
        printf("%d\n",a.arr[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, what I'm doing is almost identical to [this article](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures). However, when I compile and run this, it prints a random gibberish number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tangential to your immediate problem, note that `quaternions.c` should `#include "quaternions.h"` rather than write the definition out a second time.  The header will eventually declare functions, and those function declarations must be checked against the definitions and against the uses of those functions.  The header is the glue that allows this to be cross-checked by the compiler.

Comment: Please check print type format. If you want to print double variable type, you must use '&f' not '%d'.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler. Like I said, this is my first time using structs, so I wasn't sure how to go about formatting the header.

Comment: @linuxias: You probably mean `%f` instead of `&f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct `printf` conversion format specifier for a `double` is `%f`, not `%d`. See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for that function for further information.

You should change the line

```
printf("%d\n",a.arr[1]);
```

to:

```
printf("%f\n",a.arr[1]);
```

By using the wrong conversion format specifier, your program is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This explains why your program is printing "random gibberish" instead of the desired output.

Most good compilers will warn you if you use the wrong conversion format specifier. If your compiler doesn't warn you, then I suggest that you make sure that you have all warnings enabled. See this question for further information:

[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471)

Comment: Ah, of course. What a silly mistake. Thanks for the information about compiler warnings. My compiler didn't give me one.